# Django Userena change url guardian error

Tags: python, django, url, view

Hey there I try to use userena with django to build a website which has a clean dashboard after login in. My current problem is that userena uses a pretty high url depth.

Userena is under myproject/accounts and uses the url 'user'. Later 'dashboard'.
When logged in 127.0.0.1:8000/user/ is the userena url. In the normal state it lists all registred users. I've managed to change that to show the current logged in users profile with (accounts/urls.py):

```
url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
url(r'^', include('userena.urls')),
```

My problem is now that I want to change the normal userena urls.
Userena urls are:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/user/username/signout
127.0.0.1:8000/user/username/edit
127.0.0.1:8000/user/username/email
127.0.0.1:8000/user/username/password
....
```

I want:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/user/signout
127.0.0.1:8000/user/edit
....
```

I've tried to change both the url and the view but I get always the GuardianError.

Url change:

```
url(r'^edit', userena_views.profile_edit),
```

View change:

```
url(r'^edit', views.settings, name='settings'),
+
def settings(request):
    user = request.user
    response = userena_views.profile_edit(request, user)
    return response
```

The error:
[image]

There are probably multiple ways to archive this. Thank you for the help and sorry for the poor english.

Answer (score 1):

I found a method to solve this here http://tundebabzy.blogspot.de/2013/04/an-easy-way-to-override-third-party-app.html

I practically changed the view like in the tutorial to serve the same files like the original userena view. The case that there will be no username had me to add that extra in the view.

```
def profile_edit(request, edit_profile_form=userena_forms.EditProfileForm,
             template_name='userena/profile_form.html', success_url=None,
             extra_context=None, **kwargs):
    username = request.user

    return userena_views.profile_edit(request=request, username=username,
            edit_profile_form=edit_profile_form, template_name=template_name,
            success_url=success_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Url:

```
url(r'^edit/$', views.profile_edit, name='userena_profile_edit'),
```